# MySQL GROUP BY without aggregate instead of LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, limit

Scenario: Let's say I have a transactions table and I want details of only the **last transaction for every user**.

> So, in the example below I want this result:
>
> ```
> | userId | trxType | trxDate  |
> |--------|---------|----------|
> | 1      | c       | 20190103 |
> | 2      | a       | 20190104 |
> ```

I know this is not a good solution, but would I be right to safely assume that using GROUP BY without an aggregate, on an **ordered** subquery, would return the correct data in this case (ie. pick fields from the first column for each group)?

I tried the following test and it seems to work fine, but I've read some posts that say they are selected at random ¬_¬ (Unions are there to mimic a table to have a standalone query).

```
SELECT userid, trxType, trxDate
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT 1 AS userid, 'a' AS trxType, '20190101' AS trxDate
                UNION
                SELECT 1 AS userid, 'b' AS trxType, '20190102' AS trxDate
                UNION
                SELECT 1 AS userid, 'c' AS trxType, '20190103' AS trxDate
                UNION
                SELECT 2 AS userid, 'a' AS trxType, '20190104' AS trxDate
                UNION
                SELECT 2 AS userid, 'b' AS trxType, '20190101' AS trxDate
        ) myTable ORDER BY trxDate DESC
    ) mySubQuery
GROUP BY userid;
```

Thanks!

### Update

As I said, I know this is a bad solution and shouldn't be used. I just wanted to know if unaggregated GROUP BY selects the first item it encounters.

Anyway, in case you're looking for the best solution, I found this useful and clean as it allows for non-unique ordering fields, and also top N records per group if you want more than 1 (just edit the final condition):

```
SELECT x.userid, x.trxType, x.trxDate
FROM (
    SELECT t.userid, t.trxType, t.trxDate,
    @group_order := IF(@current_group = t.userid, @group_order + 1, 1) as group_order,
    @current_group := t.userid as current_group
    FROM transactions t
    ORDER by t.userid, t.trxDate DESC
) x
WHERE x.group_order = 1;
```

(**IMP:** always order by the grouping field first)

Comment: Never ever ever do this, the results are not predictable.  If you're going to aggregate and/or group by, every column in your query needs to be aggregated or grouped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.trxDate = (select max(t2.trxDate)
                   from transactions t2
                   where t2.userid = t.userid
                  );
```

For performance, you want an index on `transactions(userid, trxDate)`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this solution is when the ordering field is not unique. I added a better solution in the question.